# React Router 'Home is not defined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

**EDIT:** Thanks to all you shiny, happy people. The trick is to use import/export syntax to get everything up and running.

I keep getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: Home is not defined` when I am trying to implement React Router. I'm not sure what the deal is though as this should be working. Can someone spot my mistake or shed some light on how I'm doing this wrong?

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router-dom');
var BrowserRouter = ReactRouter.BrowserRouter;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
// var Switch = ReactRouter.Switch;

import Home from './Home';
import Data from './Data';


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}


module.exports = App;
```

I also tried `var Home = require('./Home');` but that didn't work either.

Below is how my Home component is set up.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Nav = require('./Nav');
var Hero = require('./Hero');
var Block = require('./Block');
var Table = require('./Table');
var Footer = require('./Footer');
var Modal = require('./Modal');

class Home extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <Hero />
        <Block />
        <Table />
        <Footer />
        <Modal />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

module.exports = Home;
```

Ok so I've updated App and Home accordingly but I'm still getting a blank page. No errors.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Home } from './Home';


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Nav } from './Nav';
import { Hero } from './Hero';
import { Block } from './Block';
import { Table } from './Table';
import { Footer } from './Footer';
import { Modal } from './Modal';

class Home extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <Hero />
        <Block />
        <Table />
        <Footer />
        <Modal />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default Home;
```

Comment: Can you show your Home component

Comment: Added! I used the below users suggest to use import { Home } from './Home'; to get past the error message but now I'm not rendering anything from Home...

Comment: You have to use it exactly like that since you are not exporting the Home component by default. Try using import in a similar manner for other components as well in HOME and do you get any errors now

Comment: I used import across the board and stopped getting errors but also ended up not rendering anything. When I looked at React in my DevConsole it just said that everything between BrowserRouter was 'null'

Comment: Got it! Had to go through the whole thing and replace everything with imports and exports. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're exporting your Home component using CommonJS but trying to import it using the ES2015 syntax. Try exporting your Home component with this syntax instead:

```
export default Home;
```

Comment: Thanks. I've done as you suggested. I think I'm closer but not there yet.

Comment: Got it! Had to go through the whole thing and replace everything with imports and exports. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I was able to help :) please mark my answer as the accepted solution if you think it was the one that helped you the most